# How can the mean be nan when no nan value is found?

Tags: nan, mean, missing-data, variance

I checked if there is nan value with math, pandas, numpy. I conclude that there is no nan value. but there is a problem with the mean and variance values. I can't reach the reason

The codes show the problem:

[image]

As if for some reason I cannot discover nan values. because according to the formula of the mean method, at least one nan value must be found for this result.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're looking to compute temperature means, using the mean prototype will return the mean of all rows and columns, therefore you must specify the column on which you wish to perform the mean prototype on, would be great if you post the complete x_train_nontreeb['Temperature(F)'].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the NaN value but checking for a NaN value in python is done this way:

```
math.isnan(x)
```

and not by isnull().

For solving the issue, maybe try to iterate through the whole list with this function to search for this NaN? I guess you've already tried it with isnull().

Another possible way would be by the nanmean() function, maybe it would give the exact result you're searching for.